# Standard Deviations for reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User Rank -or- User Percentile Rating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/user-rank-or-user-percentile-rating)

Entirely editing my answer to try and make sense here ...

Wikipedia page on [Standard Deviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

I suggest that we display a value that represents the number of standard deviations from the norm that a user is.

The Y axis is the % of users with that reputation score, the X axis plots scores from 0 to n. You could then determine where the user is in terms of rarity with regards to the entire user-base, rather than looking at a reputation score that a large volume of users could be in. So I could show up as 101 rep, and we can identify just how rare (or common) that range is in the deviations of users on SO meta (about 8,750/21,000 = 41.7% have a lower reputation than me), where as someone at 0 would be

[image]

This is similar to how people are ranked as "genius" with IQ scores, as they are in the top 2% of IQ scores.

We could give users titles for being at specific deviations.

Comment: That's funny, I don't ever seem to recall seeing the word "karma" on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's not karma, it's exp.

Comment: The distribution is quite different. The **vast** majority of users (~96%) have less than 1000 points.

Comment: Maybe he's talking about the up/downvote ratio when referring to karma

Comment: Updated so it says reputation not karma. I'm talking about the reputation point system score.

Comment: I'm talking about representing how many standard deviations you are from the norm user.

Comment: The distribution on Stack Overflow reputation is neither Normal nor Poisson nor Lorentzian, so while the standard deviation from the mean *can* be defined it does not have a obvious interpretation

Comment: Where are these users with 1,000,000 (1000k) rep?

Comment: Is there any chance we can get some terminology in here that's English, as opposed to Greek or French or Dutch? If not, some explanations, perhaps?

Comment: @Grace Note, he is not talking Dutch else I would understand. ;-).

Comment: @Gamecat Unless I am mistaken, the nomenclature of [Lorentzian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentzian_distribution) comes from [a Dutch physicist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendrik_Lorentz).

Comment: @Jon Seigel that's exactly what I'm asking, but rather than showing percentage distribution represent it as the SD.

Comment: @Grace Note, thats right: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendrik_Lorentz, sorry thought your comment was about the question and there wasn't a Dutch word (with no meaning in english) there.

Comment: Updated to make sense.

Comment: @Grace Note - Bais non! J'aime [ **les poissons** ](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuuEDDyvzuE)!

Comment: @user: quoting the wikipedia doesn't help because the distributions of reputations on stack overflow is *not peak-like*. See [StackOverflow User Statistics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9858/stackoverflow-user-statistics) which is now somewhat out of date, but shows the kind of distribution you can *expect* from this system.

Answer (score 3):

Standard deviations describe points in a specific type of distribution, a normal distribution.

Standard deviations cannot be used to describe (untransformed) scores on Stack Overflow, since scores on Stack Overflow do not follow a normal distribution.

How many standard distributions away from the "average" a point is basically describes how different the point is from that "average." This "average" is not really meaningful in the sort of one-tailed distribution that Stack Overflow scores have:

---

[image]

---

You could try some transformations...

Comment: you should invert the x-axis, you suggest Jon Skeet has so little rep that even new users outrep him

Comment: ...or *do* you want to suggest Jon Skeet's rep finally overflowed?

Comment: @Tobias - Whoops... done.

Comment: Jon Skeet is not an outlier. All the other points are outliers.

Comment: **Aside:** The standard deviation (or some similar "widthy" number) is actually meaningful on a number of peak-like distributions (not just the Gaussian). Now, time-averaged reputation velocity might have a peaked character for which a width number makes sense. Though the rep-cap may cause a discontinuity in the shape.

Comment: @dmckee - Maybe, but probably only if you discard velocities of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be awesome... ***if*** you exclude the many many users with <12 rep.

Comment: It's Definitely not a normal distribution.

Comment: Not just <12. Especially with the new Stack Exchange Network sites, people who have done naught but association to get 101 are also a thing to watch out for. However, it's a good question how to differentiate them from people who started at 1 and actually worked up to get 101 reputation...

Comment: You would definitely need to run some sort of transformation.