# Why clearly MSO-oriented questions are migrated to MSE?

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions, mso-mse-split

There is a certain number of Meta Stack Overflow-oriented questions here:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32516/189165
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17865/189165
- [StackOverflow User Statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9858/189165)

Why was they migrated to Meta Stack Exchange? Should we do something with them?

Comment: That post was not migrated from MSO. It was migrated from *Stack Overflow*!  There was no MSE in 2010; this site was still called MSO back then and migration from SO to MSO was entirely natural.

Comment: See my comment for answer below. I understand situation / process. I don't understand, why these questions now remain on MSE, where they have nearly no value? Why they're not migrated back to MSO, once MSE-MSO split is a fact?

Comment: Because there is no point in cluttering up a child meta with old discussions. The devs had no time nor desire to troll through all those old old posts and close them either. Just VTC as you find them. None of these need migrating.

Comment: The second post is not SO specific; it just predates the existence of the rest of the SE network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Meta Stack Exchange used to be Meta Stack Overflow [until last April](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014), thus it had two hats: the whole network meta like it's these days, plus the per site meta of Stack Overflow.

Note it was migrated nearly five years before the split:

> [image]

And the team decided to not mass-migrate everything back to MSO after the split. We can vote to close those questions as "pertains only to a specific site" though.

Comment: I know that. But, why wasn't that question left in MSO? What is its value in MSE?

Comment: @trejder umm, because it was migrated back in  Dec 10 '09?

Comment: See my edit @trejder, there's a special close reason after the split. :)

Comment: Thanks for an explanation. Why VTC? Why not vote to migrate back to MSO? It has certain value for MSO (rarely no for MSE).

Comment: @trejder old questions can't be migrated, not even by moderators.

Comment: That explains all. Thanks. Though this should be fixed, because result is quite confusing (at least to me).

Comment: If it bothers you so much you can try and flag as "other" pledging your case... dev can use power tools to migrate even old question, but most chances your flag will be declined.

Comment: @trejder what would be the point? SO changed over the years; it is not MS centric now as it may have been back when for example. Migrating that just means crap and clutter is being migrated and we don't like to migrate crap and clutter.